# SharePoint 2007 solution in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: 2010, 2007, visual-studio

I have a question regarding building a solution in visual studio 2010 for SharePoint 2007.
So basically I have a SharePoint 2007 and to maintain it from central location, I would like to move the current project from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010. The idea would be to just import it there and be able to build a correct wsp package.

Is this possible, and if so how to proceed?

I did a first step I've added the current 2007 solution to Visual Studio 2010, at this moment i get some errors with the assemblies because they reference 14, but i need to make them reference to 12 ... but will it work? Should i copy all the dll's to projects or how should I proceed?

Thanks